# Database for galaxy luminosity (or mass) distribution

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, galaxies, galaxy-rotation-curve, galaxy-clusters

I'm trying to get data on luminosity (or mass) distribution for galaxies.
I came across one paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.3564) which gives luminosity distribution for Andromeda.

But is there any data base where I can get the luminosity distribution for several galaxies?
The NED database (https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/) seems to give the total luminosity (not the distribution), unless I'm gathering the data incorrectly.

Comment: You may wish to try [astronomy.se].